# Exim hold domains configuration format

Tags: exim

I want to slow delivery of emails from a specific domain.

from my research i understand i can add hold_domains into the exim config file but i am unsure on the syntax for this and have had no luck finding any examples.

I know i can add

```
hold_domains *
```

and stop literally every domain but should i normally be providing a list located elsewhere or just add

```
hold_domains example.com
```

any help appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, I advise you to take this information and test it out.  Imagine you have a table named *delivery* in your database that controls delivery to a remote domain (i.e. not one that you host).  That table has several fields in it: domain, date, comment, etc.  If you add a field named "hold" that defaults to 0, then you can set it to 1 only when you want email to a specific domain to be not delivered.

The item **hold_domains** is an expanded item, but it's a main configuration option which means it's evaluated when exim starts, such as a queue runner.  If you have:

```
hold_domains = ${>\n lookup mysql {SELECT domain FROM delivery WHERE hold=1}}
```

Then each time your queue runner starts, it will do that lookup and skip delivery to any domains it finds in that list.  "The option is overridden if a message delivery is forced with the -M, -qf..." so you can manually force delivery to a domain either by manually delivering messages from the commandline with those options, by setting hold=0 for that domain, or by deleting that domain from the delivery table.  You may decide that you want a seperate field for holding due to administrative/legal issues compared to a field for holding due to delivery problems to that host.

You also would want some kind of standard method of manipulating that hold field, be it a shell or perl or python script, directly from the mysql commandline, or some web form that you build to do it.  How you control that is entirely up to you and the resources you have available.

--Edit
By the sound of your question, a database is overkill for what you want and a local file with a list of domains you want to hold will be sufficient.  For that, create a text file, for example */etc/exim/hold_domains.txt*.  Then configure the **hold_domains** to read from that file.  This is untested, I'm not sure if either will work as expected:

```
hold_domains = ${>\n lookup{*} wildlsearch{/etc/exim/hold_domains.txt}}
  *or*
hold_domains = lsearch;/etc/exim/hold_domains.txt
```

In the */etc/exim/hold_domains.txt*, you merely put one domain per line that you want to hold delivery to.

Comment: this might add another level of problems as im not entirely sure how i would get that file to access the specific mysql db?
I would for now i think rather just understand how i would add the domain names correctly. in a file or just comma seperated?